# USB installer just exits when trying to install on a Chromebook C720

Tags: system-installation, acer, chromebook

I am trying to **re**install a *full* (not Crouton, not ChrUbuntu) version of Linux on my C720 Acer Chromebook.

I already have Ubuntu on there, but it's having some problems, and requires a reinstall. I already have SeaBIOS (CoreBoot).

I've created a live image on a bootable USB, and managed to start the installer on my C720. But after selecting "Install", the computer just restarts. *Clarification:* the live distro doesn't even boot, the installer from the USB only shows its menu.

I've tried:

- Ubuntu 14.10
- Fedora 21

What's going on? How do I boot a live OS on C720?

(The architectures are correct, x86_64)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of ubuntu do you currently have on the machine?

Comment: Originally installed 14.04 and after that, upgraded in-place to 14.10. I've read some bugs may exist in 14.10's image burner, so I'll try burning from a Windows machine.

Comment: With Ubuntu ISOs you can just do `dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX` where /dev/sdx is your USB. That's a coreutil and should not have issues in ubuntu. That being said, your ISO might be corrupt. Maybe try `md5sum /path/to/iso` and compare it to the hashes [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

Comment: could you select installation of safe-mode?

Answer (score 2):

This seems related to this bug:https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1135793

I'd keep an eye on that and see if they come up with any workarounds. In the meantime you could try booting Fedora 20 with mem=1024 kernel parameters and using that or try to upgrade to Fedora 21 from there with fedup.

Comment: That's exactly the description of the problem I'm having, thanks for letting me know. Hopefully it will get fixed and the images will get updated...

Comment: looks like that bug was fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem, and have you tryed using unetbootin for windows 8, and you search for it at Google, and there you can make live install, and choose linux version it all the work for it self, and i will just use all of it capacity for the boot, and i made my working this way, and it might work fine this way

Answer (score -1):

How did you install it on there before?  It probably seems obvious, but maybe you could try the following?:

1. Boot up into the live USB
2. Back up any important files/data externally
3. Reformat the drive, so you know you're starting form a 'clean slate'.  Probably doing a thorough drive scan and system diagnostic check wouldn't be a bad idea either
4. Try reinstalling your OS(s)

Comment: *"Boot up into the live USB"* That's where the problem is. It can't boot at all, just restarts itself. Last time it simply worked. I'll try with 14.04 as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  From your question, it sounded like you could boot into the live USB, but it was restarting after you tried to do a full install to the hard drive.